# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception for arm64-v8a app on x86, armeabi-v7a, armeabi device

Tags: android, google-play, apk, abi

Every now and then I receive `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception in our production app.

I am sharing one example here. Following device received `arm64-v8a` version of our app and then crashed at launch time with `UnsatisfiedLinkError`:

- Device: vivo y23l
- cpuAbi: [   "x86",   "armeabi-v7a",   "armeabi" ]
- android 5.1.1
- Downloaded app with `arm64-v8a` abi

I am trying to understand how it is possible that a device which doesn't have arm64 cpu received this apk from Play Store.

Related guide  talks about x86 running armeabi but not arm64-v8a https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#android-platform-abi-support

> Many x86-based devices can also run armeabi-v7a and armeabi NDK
>   binaries. For such devices, the primary ABI would be x86, and the
>   second one, armeabi-v7a.

I plan to use android app bundles in coming few months. But it will still be helpful to understand whats going on here.

Worth mentioning that we release our app with separate apks for each `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, `x86_64` abi.

**Update:** Another incident:

- Device OPPO A33
- cpuAbi[
  "armeabi-v7a",
  "armeabi"
  ]
- android 4.4.4
- Downloaded app with `arm64-v8a`

Comment: Please reach out to Play developer support so this can get investigated. If you can provide all the information needed about the device, that would help as well.

Comment: Done, just emailed https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by doing the following:

Added following in proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config {
native <methods>;
void log(long, int, byte[]);
void statistics(long, int, float, float, long , int, double, double);
}

-keep class com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.AbiDetect {
  native <methods>;
}
```

and in android/build.gradle file:

I made sure mavenCentral() comes before jcenter()

I am using RN: 0.63.5

I referred to this link: [GITHUB ISSUE](https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg/issues/216)